# Include RIA Services in Solution without usual installation

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services, projects-and-solutions

I want to use WCF RIA Services without need to install this. My idea is just to reference the libraries:

`Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll` and `Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.dll`
in my Solution Libs folder.
This avoid overhead for devs and even for deployment.

This solution creates some evil hide monster? I forgetting something?

*I tried this and, well, "It works in my machine" until now.

Answer (score 2):

If you reference DLL´s that are only on your development machine, make sure your reference doesn´t point to the Globsal Assembly Cache. Otherwise the other developers can´t find the reference.

Also selecting ´Copy Local´ for the references will make sure they are copied to the bin directory so you can deploy the solution with the necessary dll´s included.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest storing the actual dll files in a References folder in the root of your project. Then add them to your project through visual studio. Once you've done that add the hintpath node to the actual project file for each reference, which will tell VS where to look for the file. This method works great especially if you are working with multiple projects because then you dont have to copy the dll files to each bin directory.

Comment: Yes, when I said `my Solution Libs folder` I'm actually doing that. Thanks